# Unable to add vertical scroll bar in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

```
<body  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-show = "dataFromRest" ng-repeat = "x in dataFromRest.posts" >       
        <div class="tittle" style="width: 25%;">                
                <a href="" ng-click="showDiv = ! showDiv" style="text-decoration: none;" ># {{x.title}} </a>
                <a href=""  style="text-decoration: none;" ng-if="!x.title"># No title</a>
                    <hr style="color: red">
                </a>
            </b>                
        </div>  
        <div class="text">              
            <div style="width: 70% ;float:right; background-color: white;">
                <div ng-show="showDiv">
                     <div style="float: right;">
                     <img id="currentPhoto" src="{{x.thread.main_image}}" onerror="this.src='noimageavailable.png'" width="300px" height="250px" style="float: right;">
                     </div>
                     <div style="color: purple;text-align: center;font-size:21px">
                        {{x.title}}
                     </div><br>
                     <div>
                        {{x.text}}
                     </div>
                     <b>
                        URL:-
                     </b>
                     <a href="{{x.url}}" style=" color: blue;"> To see in details, click here! </a><br> <br>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i am working on news feed module . I have two div's ,in first div (left-side) list of all news title is displayed and on right side div the description and image about that title is shown.But i am not able to add vertical scroll bar on left-side div(title-div),if i apply div then it goes to every particular title only.and second one is when page is load the first title, description will automatically load, so how to do this two things?

Answer (score 0):

**Add a wrapper.**

The overflow scroll goes to all `tittle` because the `title` class is inside `ng-repeat` and thus is repeated for every individual title.

Add another wrapper div outside `ng-repeat` and apply overflow scroll to that.

```
    <div class="wrapper">
     <div ng-show = "dataFromRest" ng-repeat = "x in dataFromRest.posts" >       
        <div class="tittle" style="width: 25%;">                
                <a href="" ng-click="showDiv = ! showDiv" style="text-decoration: none;" ># {{x.title}} </a>
                <a href=""  style="text-decoration: none;" ng-if="!x.title"># No title</a>
                    <hr style="color: red">
                </a>
            </b>                
        </div>  
        <div class="text">              
            <div style="width: 70% ;float:right; background-color: white;">
                <div ng-show="showDiv">
                     <div style="float: right;">
                     <img id="currentPhoto" src="{{x.thread.main_image}}" onerror="this.src='noimageavailable.png'" width="300px" height="250px" style="float: right;">
                     </div>
                     <div style="color: purple;text-align: center;font-size:21px">
                        {{x.title}}
                     </div><br>
                     <div>
                        {{x.text}}
                     </div>
                     <b>
                        URL:-
                     </b>
                     <a href="{{x.url}}" style=" color: blue;"> To see in details, click here! </a><br> <br>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- .wrapper -->
```

And add `overflow:scroll` to wrapper.

```
.wrapper {
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

Note that this will create scroll for both title and text combined. Since they are in single wrapper. If you want different then, you will have to create two different wrappers with two different ng-repeat.